# Two questions about real time observers and Stripe on server side Dart with Aqueduct

Tags: firebase, dart, stripe-payments, server-side, aqueduct

I'm going to switch from using Firebase only for back end to using my own server using Aqueduct with a PostgreSQL db for most functionalities and keep using only Google Cloud Storage and Firebase Cloud Messaging.
As for Stripe payments I will have to set some Firebase Cloud Functions, I'd like to make my own endpoints in Aqueduct instead.
I'm not sure there is a Stripe SDK to use in Aqueduct, as for Firebase, but as Stripe has a cUrl API I'm sure I can get to use that.
Is this a viable solution for Stripe payments?
Are real time observers available on Aqueduct + PostgreSQL as I'm using them on certain Firestore collections?
I searched for it but haven't found any Stripe + Aqueduct specific guide or post..
Any advice will be very helpful.
As always many thanks for the help.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't an official Stripe Dart library, there is a community one, though I can't speak to its completeness/correctness: https://gitlab.com/exitlive/stripe-dart

Otherwise you're either making HTTP requests ([using the CURL API docs as a guide](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=curl)) in Dart, or maybe proxying them through some Cloud Functions so you can use the Javascript library.

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering. I actually found this https://pub.dev/packages/stripedart which is just the Stripe API  for server side Dart. Did you know this package ? Looking at the docs I see everything I need, Customers ( buyers ), Payment intents.. and for Stripe Connect as I use, I see Accounts ( Merchants ). So I guess I'm sorted with this. I'll just make endpoints in Aqueduct and that would be my equivalent of Firebase Cloud Functions to manage Stripe right?

Comment: That's probably correct, but I'm not familiar enough with any of the bits here to know for sure - but it sounds like a good strategy to test out in testmode. :)